# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch while uploading file with google drive api v3 and .net6 web api

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

[image: the error description by google]
my code snippet is

```
using (var stream =
      new FileStream(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
        "Admin",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
  }
```

I have even changed the redirect URI in the credentials section of the cloud console but in error random redirect uri pops up help me fix this issue please

Answer (score 0):

You need to add exactly this redirect uri to google cloud console

[image]

it must be exact including the trailing / and the port number.

You should also ensure that your application is running with a static port number.  If the port number changes then you will get a  miss match again.